# android.view.InflateException:Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView,InvocationTargetException

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-studio-2.1

while I'm trying to login my app on samsung galaxy s3 mini(4.2.2) i got crash, except this device it's working on all other devices, could any one please help me out in detail how to tackle this problem. thanks.

logcat is

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.redkan09.collegeapp/com.example.redkan09.collegeapp.DrawerActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2301)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5285)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:693)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                                                                                      at com.example.redkan09.collegeapp.DrawerActivity.onCreate(DrawerActivity.java:50)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5284)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2301) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5285) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
>                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:693) 
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752) 
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
>                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
>                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                                                                                      at com.example.redkan09.collegeapp.DrawerActivity.onCreate(DrawerActivity.java:50) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5284) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2301) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5285) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
>                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenu
>                                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:104)
>                                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:95)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593) 
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:693) 
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752) 
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
>                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
>                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                                                                                      at com.example.redkan09.collegeapp.DrawerActivity.onCreate(DrawerActivity.java:50) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5284) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2301) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5285) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
>                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

```html
my gradle file is

ndroid {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.redkan09.collegeapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        renderscriptTargetApi 14
                renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
}
```

## my navigation drawer xml is ##

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_drawer"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_drawer_drawer"
   />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

### header layout for nav drawer is

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
              android:background="@drawable/myshape"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="33dp"
        android:id="@+id/profName"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:text="Android Studio"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

    <!-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
            android:text="android.studio@android.com"/>
    </!-->


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using .xml images in drawable for Navigation view icons ?

Comment: no, i'm using .png images in mipmap folder, please check my recent edit i have posted my navigation drawer xml file's

Comment: Are you using any theme for you activity.

Comment: it's AppTheme.Base contains colorprimary,dark